# Angular function is not going inside ngOnChanges

Tags: angular

I have below code. However my function is not going inside `ngOnChanges` function.
Is there anythings thats missing in my code?

```
export class Component implements OnChanges {
  form: FormGroup;

  @Input()
  loadable: LoadableValue<form[]>;

  @Output()
  updateEvent = new EventEmitter<form[]>();

  constructor(public translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      test: new FormArray([]),
    });
    this.patch();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['loadable']) {
      if (this.loadable?.state === LOADABLE_STATE.SUCCESS) {
        console.log('test')
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Parent component:

```
  // Form Group and Validators
  @ViewChild('formContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  formContainer!: ViewContainerRef;
  this._component = this.formContainer?.createComponent(component);
  if (this._component) {
     this._component.instance.key = type;
     this._component.instance.formData.next(.form);
   }
```

parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-container',
  template: `
    <app-update
      [loadable]="loadable$" | async 
    ></app-update>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
```

I need to set data from on change event.

Comment: inside your if, try testing for changes['loadable']?.currentValue, when it is not null you have to affect it to your variable this.loadable, then you can run the second test.

Comment: @hasnaas Thanks. But someone onChanges is not working at all

Comment: onChanges normally always work. But if your input if of type reference, you have to force change on the parent, for example, via a new affectation

Comment: @hasnaas Do you have any sample?

Comment: Could you add @Component decorator and usage example?

Comment: Why i dont see how you are setting `loadable` anywhere?

Comment: Please dont SPAM with posts that are missing critical details anyway 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266692/angular-error-on-passing-data-from-parent-to-child  just update this one with component template etc.

Comment: How am i suppose to know what is `Component class`, how it relates to the `@Component` snippet etc and what is wrong with the code that is not included here at all.